# how to call a service from an activity?

Tags: android

I have a service which starts an activity by

```
                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), dialog.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

But I'm not sure how to pass a call when this new activity finishes to the service?

Note that "startActivityForResult" does not work from a service. ;)

On the other hand, maybe there is some "when focus comes back" listener for the service?

Thanks!

edit:

activity finishes by

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TotalKeyboard.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);

finish();
```

yet this, in service, doesn't get the call

```
     @Override public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
     {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aaa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Comment: I think it would be better to tell us why do you want to do this. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Basically I want a dialog with option to appear and let the service know, what the user has chosen. since the service can't show a dialog, I've created an activity for it. i.e. service launches and activity, which launches a dialog. when the user makes his choice, the activity finishes. now just need to let the service know, that the activity has finished.

Answer (score 2):

when you try to `start service` which is `already running` then it's `onCreate` method does not get the call but it's `onStart()` methods gets the call......you can use this property to meet your need...

Comment: hmm... can't find an onStart() method in my service, can't add it either.

Comment: Override this method:  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) { }

Comment: doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't seem to do anything either. what should i put in (Intent intent, int startid) ?

Comment: if your activity is finishing and you are starting the service again then onStart() will get called...you got the notification that your activity finishing ....now perform your task accordingly..

Comment: see edit above. it doesn't show the toast, after activity is finished.

Comment: put debugger in onstart() method and check if you are getting the call there or not.....startservice before finish() statement..

Comment: just a sec, its giving me SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent without permission android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3092/discussion-between-roger-and-vineet-shukla)

Answer (score 2):

You never get `foucs` on a `Service`. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, and maybe this is not the best solution but you can `bound` from you `Activity` to the `Service` and declare a method in your `Service` class and then you can call that method from your `Activity`, after you are `bound` to your service.

EDIT: You can simulate a dialog show from a `Service` by creating an `Activity` that looks like a dialog. You can do this by setting the `theme` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <activity
        android:name="myPackages.ui.DialogActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" />
```

You can declare a `method` in your `Service` let's say:

```
   public void performAction(boolean userChoice){
        //implementation
   }
```

and in your `DialogActivity` class you can `bound` to your `Service` class and on the press of a button you can call :

```
  mBoundService.performAction(true);
```

or

```
  mBoundService.performAction(false);
```

based on the user choice.

Answer (score 1):

In Short , Activity itself has to take care of this.

Comment: how? i.e. how should an Activity tell a service "I'm done, its up to you now". :)

Comment: Dialog Activity has different listeners , For Ex : OK , Cancel. you can call finish(); and tell your service that its your call now